# Why i am getting multiple images while using Function() in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I use the following Jquery for calendar http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

My source is as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_textbox1').datepick({showOnFocus: false, showTrigger: '#calImg'});
});
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="Server">
</asp:TextBox>
<img src="calendar.gif" alt="Popup" id="calImg" class="trigger" />
```

But i am getting multiple images when i see on my browser why this is happening

[Link http://i53.tinypic.com/2v0ykd1.png](http://i53.tinypic.com/2v0ykd1.png)

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by getting multiple images and what is `datepick`? (btw, your image seems to be broken)

Comment: Updated my question check once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how this plugin works internally, but you can see in the example ( http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html -> Invocation -> From image only)  that they hide the original image:

```
<div style="display: none;"> 
    <img id="calImg" src="img/calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the datepick-plugin clones the image. Possible workaround is to just remove the image after loading the datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_textbox1').datepick({showOnFocus: false, showTrigger: '#calImg'});
$("#calImg").remove();
});
</script>
```